# Remove white border from image

Tags: html, css, image, border

Tried border: none; with no avail.

```
#header .bg
{
float: right;
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
border: none;
}
```

Now for the html...

```
<body>
<div id="header">
<img class="bg" src="http://hdwallpapermania.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Beautiful-    Beach-Landscape-HD.png"> 
</div>
```

Comment: why the space between image name? can't see any white border on image. have a look. http://jsbin.com/tutiwipo/1/edit . Seems some other css style is overlapping.

Comment: Do you need something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/WMQVw/

Comment: What white border are you talking about? I don't think you've provided enough code and/or explanation to diagnose your problem. http://jsfiddle.net/LX6g9/1/

Comment: @AppleBud you forgot closing `</div>` on your code.

Comment: @user3758781 Show us your full HTML/CSS, and if possible create jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use:

```
<div id="header" style="background-size:cover; background-image:url(http://hdwallpapermania.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Beautiful-Beach-Landscape-HD.png);">
```

instead?
Or, even better:

```
<div id="header"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(http://hdwallpapermania.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Beautiful-Beach-Landscape-HD.png);
}
```

Comment: I guess OP want to show the carousel effect on image. that's why he used `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Example but with an image in the `body` tag: [Live version](http://jsfiddle.net/MeCq8/8/)

HTML:

```
<body>
   <div id="header">
   </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
  background-image: url(http://hdwallpapermania.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Beautiful-Beach-Landscape-HD.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top left
}
```

Comment: May be there is some purpose for using `<img>` element.

Comment: @KheemaPandey yes could be but the question looks like he needs a seemless background image. That is why I removed `<img>` and implemented the background via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

`img` tag is a **Replaced Element** which means by default it's `display` is set to `inline` which also means `line-height` value effects it, which is probably why you have negative space around it.

**SOLUTION:** Add `display: block;` property on your `img`.

Also in your particular case you should use [CSS Normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.1/normalize.css) if you aren't using it - This will remove any extra spacing caused by any other element i.e body.